# Chrome <td> border-top bleeds across row

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

I have some HTML that gets rendered and I'm experiencing an issue with Chrome where the border for a `<td>` is bleeding across the rest of the row. However, only the top border is bleeding.

I've been able to re-create the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ydVDv/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the border-collapse css clause that's causing this.
Do this to fix it:

> ```
> table
> {
>     border-collapse: separate;
> }
> ```

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/ydVDv/4/

Comment: Thanks. You just saved me from a headache.